# What happens exactly behind the scene when i run bundle exec cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, capybara

Is there any documentation or something where i can find out what happens exactly when i try run cucumber scenarios for my web app.

- when and how it starts the server?

I am using Capybara , webkit , headless gem as my tech stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend tracing through the code of Capybara and Cucumber (ideally for the versions of the gems that you're using). I found it easier to work backward from where Capybara starts the server rather than forward from when Cucumber is invoked.

[`Capybara::Server`](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/d76c013b58fdc189bb855be3ebeb150c5162abaa/lib/capybara/server.rb) is the class that is responsible for starting the server.

[`Capybara::Session` creates an instance of `Capybara::Server`](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/e445399fe308e641a7b8879a388372b2ee333130/lib/capybara/session.rb#L56).

Setting your driver to :webkit gets used when [`Capybara#current_session` creates a new instance of `Capybara::Session`](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/d76c013b58fdc189bb855be3ebeb150c5162abaa/lib/capybara.rb#L244).

[`page`, a method in Capybara's DSL, just returns `current_session`](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/f83edc2a515a3a4fd80eef090734d14de76580d3/lib/capybara/dsl.rb#L45).

All of the DSL methods like `visit` [get sent to the `current_session` through `page`](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/f83edc2a515a3a4fd80eef090734d14de76580d3/lib/capybara/dsl.rb#L49). At the top of the DSL file, there's a comment that says ["When using capybara/dsl, the Session is initialized automatically for you."](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/e445399fe308e641a7b8879a388372b2ee333130/lib/capybara/session.rb#L24)

Either by using cucumber-rails or [by manually requiring capybara/cucumber](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/4f678b2bbd6ab3a6de399725ad0fd1c143f38b9f/README.md#using-capybara-with-cucumber), you get the [capybara DSL methods included in Cucumber's World](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/f83edc2a515a3a4fd80eef090734d14de76580d3/lib/capybara/cucumber.rb#L4).

I haven't used cucumber in a while, but I think I remember them removing any pre-populated step definitions from cucumber, so there's not actually any place I can think of to link to in Cucumber's code, but the first time a step definition calls a Capybara DSL method looks like when the server gets started up.